# What’s the word for the habit of writing “play’d” or “revolv’d”?

Tags: single-word-requests, pronunciation, history, apostrophe, contractions

I’m working on an 18<sup>th</sup>-century manuscript, and I’m trying to explain to others the use of *’d* in past tense verbs.

Is there a word that encompasses the usage of *’d* in early 18<sup>th</sup>-century manuscripts? I’m thinking of words like *play’d* instead of *played*, or *revolv’d* instead of *revolved*.

Comment: Omission apostrophe perhaps. http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/apostrophe-american#apostrophes_showing_omission http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Early_English_practice

Comment: You want a word that means somebody used an apostrophe to represent missing letters not pronounced in speech?  What, like a contraction then?

Comment: The Chicago Manual of Style allows OD'd for overdosed, and the AP Stylebook recommends OK'd for okayed. cc'd, bcc'd, tp'd http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/do-you-use-an-apostrophe-to-make-OK-past-tense.aspx

Comment: FUN TRIVIA: Shakespeare often used *–’d* because in his time *–ed* was pronounced as an extra syllable unless clipped by an apostrophe: *wrong’d* would be one syllable, while *wronged* would be two. Now that we no longer pronounce most *–ed* endings, the apostrophe isn’t necessary. For some reason convention stuck with the apostrophe replacement in possessive endings ( *-es* ) but not past tense ( *-ed* ). http://realgrammar.wordpress.com/apostrophes/

Comment: When you write *played* it could be pronounced with either two syllables or with one.  (Nowadays almost always with one, but perhaps not so clear in the past.)  In poetry, or other writing to be read aloud, the writer may want to specify the one syllable pronunciation by writing *play'd*.  Or the two-syllable pronunciation by writing *playèd*.

Comment: @GEdgar I’d love to see an example of (preferably published, not invented) verse whose meter demands a two-syllable *playèd* version.

Comment: It is not just 18th century, but even 16th. Also please note that it is not just for past-tense verbs alone, since “three-person’d God” is not a past-tense form in: *Batter my heart, three-person’d God ; for you /
 As yet but knock ; breathe, shine, and seek to mend ; /
 That I may rise, and stand, o’erthrow me, and bend /
 Your force, to break, blow, burn, and make me new. /
 I, like an usurp’d town, to another due, /
 Labour to admit you, but O, to no end.* —John Donne (1572–1631), Holy Sonnet XIV

Comment: I think a two-syllable *played* is unlikely, since *play* ends with a vowel, but most verbs had their past tense pronounced either with one or two syllables at the time, so putting in the apostrophe for a one-syllable pronunciation was probably a common practice at the time.

Comment: Perhaps *playèd* is unlikely, but of course you do find things like *stoppèd* ... (Shakespeare Sonnet 112: "To critic and to flatt’rer stoppèd are.")

Comment: Google can find strange things.  *Excalibur, An Arthurian Drama* (by R. A. Cram, 1893) page 137: "I thought ye playèd pander to the king."

Comment: *Hesperides* (1648, Robert Herrick) "As if they playèd at bo-peep,"

Comment: I searched through Shakespeare, and it looks like he never used playèd or stayèd, although he used lots of other two-syllable past tenses like passèd, and used play'd and stay'd many times. But apparently other people did.

Answer (score 6):

You may be looking for ***elision***, defined as:

> omission of one or more sounds (such as a vowel, a consonant, or a whole syllable) in a word or phrase, producing a result that is easier for the speaker to pronounce | *[source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision)*

It's possible to make a case for other forms of [reduction](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_%28linguistics%29) - such as a contraction - but in your question you state that historical context is key. Given that *-ed* suffixes were once pronounced as a separate syllable, I would almost certainly think that elision is appropriate to describe the usage of *'d* to indicate the "omission of one or more sounds".

Comment: Wonder what elision has to do with the apostrophe.

Answer (score 2):

The '**past tense apostrophe**' in contrast to the 'possessive apostrophe'. *… there might be as many as half a dozen cases where Adair's used a past tense apostrophe* (e.g. "*vanish'd*") ([Toon](http://tooncryforhelp.blogspot.in/2009/04/books-read-in-march-part-two.html))

> I can’t wait until she’s all **deck’d** out in her poodle skirt to go to the 50's party.

(from a [comment](http://realgrammar.wordpress.com/apostrophes/) on *realgrammar*)

> As when that statue first with classic grace The clement Caesar's palace **deck’d**, …
>   ([*Fables in song*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%22as%20when%20that%20statue%20first%20with%20classic%20grace%20the%20clement%20caesar%27s%20palace%22&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://archive.org/stream/fablesinsong01lytt/fablesinsong01lytt_djvu.txt&ei=v8BmUcDCJcGMrQeAl4GgAQ&usg=AFQjCNGMMIdpXHYgW0ekmAYbZiRNRFm81g&bvm=bv.45107431,d.bmk))

As to its being out of fashion today, see the FUN TRIVIA comment of mine above.
And of course,

> [**Punk’d**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punk%27d), [*punk’d*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=punk%27d)

among the exceptions that brought *’d* back into fashion.
*subpoena'd* (*subpoenaed*), *ski'd* (*skied*), *echo'd* (*echoed*). -[Curtis](http://curtis.cleverness.us/lang/apostrophe)

Comment: Examples don't actually answer the question "Is there a word that encompasses the usage of ***'d***?" though, surely?

Comment: I haven't voted at all.

Comment: But you did the damage already - lol. So I suppose you know what such a comment does. Anyways.

Comment: A very interesting aside here: http://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/how-to-spell-1d-or-is-it-1ed/#comment-6225

Answer (score -2):

The word you're searching for is "syncope." From Wiki:

In phonology, syncope (/ˈsɪŋkəpiː/; Greek: syn- + koptein "to strike, cut off") is the loss of one or more sounds from the interior of a word, especially the loss of an unstressed vowel. It is found both in synchronic analysis of languages and diachronics. Its opposite, whereby sounds are added, is epenthesis.

As a poetic device

Sounds may be removed from the interior of a word as a rhetorical or poetic device, whether for embellishment or for the sake of the meter.

```
Latin commo[ve]rat > poetic commorat ("he had moved")
English hast[e]ning > poetic hast'ning
English heav[e]n > poetic heav'n
English over > poetic o'er
English never > poetic ne'er
```

END WIKI ENTRY

Here are examples in the final two stanzas of Blake's 'Introduction' from "Songs of Innocence" (1789):

Piper, sit thee down and write
In a book, that all may read.
So he vanish'd from my sight,
And I pluck'd a hollow reed,

And I made a rural pen,
And I stain'd the water clear,
And I wrote my happy songs
Every child may joy to hear.

Comment: Syncope is a regular, phonological process. Indicating elision of sounds by apostrophes in writing is a different matter altogether.